# Extracting summary from selected records as a division of values

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, division

Input table is like this:

| Year | Region | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Asia | 01 | 15 |
| 2021 | Europe | 02 | 35 |
| 2021 | Asia | 03 | 45 |
| 2022 | Europe | 04 | 49 |

I'm selecting entries by the year, region and id:

```
SELECT year,
       region,
       id,
       value
FROM my_table
WHERE region = 'Asia'
  AND year = 2021
  AND (id = 01 OR id = 03)
```

And the result is:

| Year | Region | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Asia | 01 | 15 |
| 2021 | Asia | 03 | 45 |

Then I need to divide the value in the string with ID 03 (45) by the value in the string with ID 01 (15) and get the result (3) under the selected strings, like this:

| Year | Region | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Asia | 01 | 15 |
| 2021 | Asia | 03 | 45 |
| 2021 | Result |  | 3 |

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT year,
    region,
    (id = 03 / id = 01),
    value
FROM my_table
WHERE region = 'Asia'
    AND year = 2021
    AND (id = 01 OR id = 03)
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it ever possible in SQLite and what should the request be?

Comment: Will be there only 2 records for filtered year and region or multiple IDs are possible? If it is what is your calculation policy?

Comment: Yes, only 2 records for most of the cases. Sometimes the result will be additionaly divided by 12  to calculate a monthly average

Comment: Can you update your post with cases when there are more than 2 records and several partitions?

Comment: Instead I'd rather say I need to perform a series of the 2-records divisions (like id2/id1, id5/id4 etc) but it looks like the whole approach should be different this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea could be using window functions inside a subquery, to select the first and the last values you've filtered with your subquery. Once your values are selected, you divide one over the other. Then use `UNION ALL` to gather the results of the subquery and the summary record.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Year_,
           Region,
           ID,
           Value
    FROM my_table
    WHERE Region = 'Asia'
      AND Year_ = 2021
      AND ID IN (01, 03)
)
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 2021, 'Result', NULL, 
                1.0* FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) /
                  FIRST_VALUE(Value) OVER(ORDER BY ID)
FROM cte
```

**Output**:

| Year_ | Region | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Asia | 1 | 15 |
| 2021 | Asia | 3 | 45 |
| 2021 | Result | null | 3 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g2QnpjmVW2A11kVaE1wzCD/1).

Comment: A little question: if there will be 45/14 = 3.214, it gives only 3 as a result, how to set the desired number of decimal places?

Comment: It's sufficient to multiply one of the values by "1.0", so that SQLite converts it to float and runs a floating point division. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you once again, appreciate your help!